# JDBC Thin layer encryption in Application Servers Data Sources

Tags: database, encryption, jdbc, datasource, oc4j

I came across an interesting article which shows how we can transparently encrypt jdbc connections using java thin client.

http://javasight.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/network-data-encryption-and-integrity-for-thin-jdbc-clients/

However I want to know how this can be achieved for application servers (like oc4j) datasources.

Answer (score 1):

It can be similarly done. I believe on the Oracle AS there is an option at the bottom of the page when you create datasource which says add properties. I believe you can add the following over there and give it a try.

```
// Set the Client encryption level  
"oracle.net.encryption_client" = Service.getLevelString(level)  

// Set the Client encryption selected list  
"oracle.net.encryption_types_client"= "(RC4_40)"

// Set the Client integrity level  
"oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client"= Service.getLevelString(level)  

// Set the client integrity selected list  
"oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client"="( MD5 )"
```

If it works out. Please let us know.

Thanks,
Franklin.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply somehow, but for any one who come across this question again

***For Enryption/Integrity:***

you will need to insert this properties manually in $J2EE_HOME/config/data-sources.xml as follows : -not tested thoroughly but should work, at least with little twicking , but should be using OracleDataSource factory class -

```
<connection-factory factory-class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" user=... >
     <connection-properties>
        <property name="oracle.net.encryption_client" value="REQUIRED123"/>
        <property name="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client" value="(SHA1123)"/>
        <property name="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client" value="REQUIRED"/>
        <property name="oracle.net.encryption_types_client" value="(AES256)"/>
     </connection-properties>
  </connection-factory>
```

***For SSL :***

check the "Configuring a TCPS Data Source" section in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13977/configssl.htm)

Franklin's solution won't work because properties allowed to be added in OC4J are limited to some enumerated values, so no property like "oracle.net.encryption_client" for example can't be added ... instead you will get this [oc4j error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8aNp.jpg)